# need an explanation about this error "Specified cast is not valid."

Tags: vb.net

here is my code

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        myFunction()
    End Sub

    Private Sub myFunction()
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com")
        While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
        TextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.OuterText.ToString
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        myFunction()
    End Sub
```

when i run this and click the button1 it works fine but when i change my button1 to this:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub
```

i'm getting this error message "Specified cast is not valid"

my goal here is very simple
1. click a button to load a page
2. wait for page to load completely
3. then grab the outerText of the page

Comment: You can not directly access form controls from within a backgroundworker or other thread type. Why do you not just use the WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted event?

Comment: i can use this Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False code to access the form control but my question is why i can not do that. any explanation?

Comment: The point of a BGW is to do some long running task in the background leaving the UI responsive.  The ReportProgress method lets the BGW send info back to the UI when needed. `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False` is not an answer.  None of this should be needed - an event is fired when the page is loaded

Comment: CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls only works in debug more I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Like already suggested, you should be using the web browser control's [**`DocumentCompleted` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) to determine when the page is fully loaded. [**`Application.DoEvents()` is bad**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfoscoding/2005/08/06/keeping-your-ui-responsive-and-the-dangers-of-application-doevents/), and should not be used to keep your UI responsive!

I have no idea where that code of yours originally comes from, nor why so many use it, but it is **BAD PRACTICE!**

The correct approach is to use the `DocumentCompleted` event:

```
Private Sub myFunction()
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com")
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    If WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
        TextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.OuterText 'No need to call ToString() since 'OuterText' already is a string.
    End If
End Sub
```

Also, skip the `BackgroundWorker`. You cannot access the `WebBrowser` from a background thread without invoking to the UI thread anyway.

---

Coincidentally, I answered [**a similar question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42363789/3740093) just a few hours ago...