# Get innerHTML from span element with getElementsByName

Tags: html, vb.net

How can i get innerHtml from a span element with getElementsByName?

HTML

```
<TD class="white"><span name="List[0].Name"/>Michael Jackson</span></TD>
```

I try this:

```
Dim InternetExplorer As Object = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
InternetExplorer.Navigate("www.test.html")
Do While InternetExplorer.Application.Busy Or InternetExplorer.Application.readyState <> 4
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
Loop
Dim value = InternetExplorer.document.getElementsByName("List[0].Name")(0).innerHTML
```

Error : ***Object variable or With block variable not set***

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you _**should not**_ use `Application.DoEvents()`! Use the [**`DocumentComplete` event**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42366199/3740093) instead.

Comment: @VisualVincent I know, but the application doesn't run on the target system with a reference to the "Microsoft Internet Control" Object.

Comment: @SLaks Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: The event still exists. You should be able to subscribe to it via late-binding. -- Also, why _doesn't_ the application reference `Microsoft Internet Controls`? If you can access `InternetExplorer.Application` you should have access to MIC as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
Dim value = InternetExplorer.document.getElementsByName("List[0].Name").item(0).textContent
```

recently I've lost like... 3days on this issue in IE :)

hope this saves your hair,, I've lost mine :)