# VB.NET Sub inside of a Function? What is this?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

So I'm reading through my source code looking for places to improve the code when I come across this unholy chunk of code.

```
Public Function ReadPDFFile(filePath As String,
                 Optional maxLength As Integer = 0) As List(Of String)

    Dim sbContents As New Text.StringBuilder

    Dim cArrayType As Type = GetType(PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.Objects.CArray)
    Dim cCommentType As Type = GetType(PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.Objects.CComment)
    Dim cIntegerType As Type = GetType(PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.Objects.CInteger)
    Dim cNameType As Type = GetType(PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.Objects.CName)
    Dim cNumberType As Type = GetType(PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.Objects.CNumber)
    Dim cOperatorType As Type = GetType(PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.Objects.COperator)
    Dim cRealType As Type = GetType(PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.Objects.CReal)
    Dim cSequenceType As Type = GetType(PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.Objects.CSequence)
    Dim cStringType As Type = GetType(PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.Objects.CString)
    Dim opCodeNameType As Type = GetType(PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.Objects.OpCodeName)

    Dim ReadObject As Action(Of PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.Objects.CObject) = Sub(obj As PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.Objects.CObject)

                                                                            Dim objType As Type = obj.GetType

                                                                            Select Case objType
                                                                                Case cArrayType
                                                                                    Dim arrObj As PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.Objects.CArray = DirectCast(obj, PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.Objects.CArray)
                                                                                    For Each member As PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.Objects.CObject In arrObj
                                                                                        ReadObject(member)
                                                                                    Next
                                                                                Case cOperatorType
                                                                                    Dim opObj As PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.Objects.COperator = DirectCast(obj, PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.Objects.COperator)
                                                                                    Select Case System.Enum.GetName(opCodeNameType, opObj.OpCode.OpCodeName)
                                                                                        Case "ET", "Tx"
                                                                                            sbContents.Append(vbNewLine)
                                                                                        Case "Tj", "TJ"
                                                                                            For Each operand As PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.Objects.CObject In opObj.Operands
                                                                                                ReadObject(operand)
                                                                                            Next
                                                                                        Case "QuoteSingle", "QuoteDbl"
                                                                                            sbContents.Append(vbNewLine)
                                                                                            For Each operand As PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.Objects.CObject In opObj.Operands
                                                                                                ReadObject(operand)
                                                                                            Next
                                                                                        Case Else
                                                                                            'Do Nothing
                                                                                    End Select
                                                                                Case cSequenceType
                                                                                    Dim seqObj As PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.Objects.CSequence = DirectCast(obj, PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.Objects.CSequence)
                                                                                    For Each member As PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.Objects.CObject In seqObj
                                                                                        ReadObject(member)
                                                                                    Next
                                                                                Case cStringType
                                                                                    sbContents.Append(DirectCast(obj, PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.Objects.CString).Value)
                                                                                Case cCommentType, cIntegerType, cNameType, cNumberType, cRealType
                                                                                    'Do Nothing
                                                                                Case Else
                                                                                    Throw New NotImplementedException(obj.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName)
                                                                            End Select

                                                                        End Sub

    Using pd As PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument = PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(filePath, PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfDocumentOpenMode.ReadOnly)

        For Each page As PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage In pd.Pages

            ReadObject(PdfSharp.Pdf.Content.ContentReader.ReadContent(page))

            If maxLength > 0 And sbContents.Length >= maxLength Then
                If sbContents.Length > maxLength Then
                    sbContents.Remove(maxLength - 1, sbContents.Length - maxLength)
                End If
                Exit For
            End If

            sbContents.Append(vbNewLine)

        Next

    End Using

    'Return sbContents.ToString

    Dim ReturnList As New List(Of String)
    For Each Line In sbContents.ToString.Split(vbNewLine)
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Line.Trim) Then

        Else
            ReturnList.Add(Line.Trim)
        End If
    Next

    Return ReturnList

End Function
```

All this does is read the text parts of a PDF using PDFSharp. What caught my eye however was line 17. Is that a Sub inside of the function?

So, what exactly is this Sub inside of a function? I didn't write this code so I've never seen anything like this before.

How does this work exactly and why wouldn't I use a function to do the processing and then return the results?

In short, my question is, what is this, how does it work, and why would I want to use something like this?

Comment: Put your cursor on `Action(of ...` and then press F1

Comment: A `sub` that big should be extracted. This is a code smell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a so-called [**Lambda expression**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions). They're used to create inline (or more correctly: in-method) methods, which makes them more dynamic than normal methods.

In your example a lambda expression is not necessary and only makes the code harder to understand. I suppose the author of that code wrote a lambda expression instead of a separate method in order to not expose `ReadObject` to any outside code.

One of the best uses for a lambda expression IMO is when you want to make thread-safe calls to the UI thread, for instance:

```
If Me.InvokeRequired = True Then
    Me.Invoke(Sub() TextBox1.Text = "Process complete!")
Else
    TextBox1.Text = "Process complete!"
End If
```

...where the same code without a lambda would look like this:

```
Delegate Sub UpdateStatusTextDelegate(ByVal Text As String)

...somewhere else...

If Me.InvokeRequired = True Then
    Me.Invoke(New UpdateStatusTextDelegate(AddressOf UpdateStatusText), "Process complete!")
Else
    UpdateStatusText("Process complete!")
End If

...end of somewhere else...

Private Sub UpdateStatusText(ByVal Text As String)
    TextBox1.Text = Text
End Sub
```

There are also other examples where lambda expressions are useful, for instance if you want to initialize a variable but do some processing at first:

```
Public Class Globals
    Public Shared ReadOnly Value As Integer = _
        Function()
            DoSomething()
            Dim i As Double = CalculateSomething(3)
            Return Math.Floor(3.45 * i)
        End Function.Invoke()
    ...
End Class
```

---

Yet another usage example is for creating partially dynamic event handlers, like [**this answer of mine**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42366199/3740093).

Comment: I'm going to factor out the code I have. It was a copy paste from SO since my PDF skills aren't very good. I'm also bookmarking the link since I've been using DoEvents ironically with automation in web browser controls... Marking this as the answer since I didn't need tissues for my nose with this one.

Comment: @Kayot : Glad I could help... I think? -- I'm not quite sure how I should interpret `I didn't need tissues for my nose with this one`, but I hope that is something good and I hope my answer was helpful. :)

Comment: Nose bleed from extremely complicated explanations. Think MSDN ^-^