# VB.NET Block until user inputs text in child form?

Tags: .net, vb.net, user-input, wait, blocking

I am creating a 2nd custom form programmatically, and trying to pause execution on the calling thread until a required value is inputted in the child form.  My current implementation is blocking my ability to input the needed value in the child form.  Makes more sense with code example of course, so here:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Task.Run(Sub()
                 Dim AnswerSolverForm As New AnswerSolvingForm
                 Dim answer As New Answer
                 AnswerSolverForm.AddAnswer(answer)
                 AnswerSolverForm.Show()
                 answer.WaitUntilSolved()
                 Debug.WriteLine(answer.Value)
             End Sub)
End Sub

Public Class AnswerSolvingForm

    Private _answers As New List(Of Answer)

    Public ReadOnly Property Answers As List(Of Answer)
        Get
            Return _answers
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        _answers.Item(0).Value = txtAnswer.Text
        _answers.RemoveAt(0)
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddAnswer(answer As Answer)
        _answers.Add(answer)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Answer

    Private _mre As Threading.ManualResetEvent
    Private _value As String

    Public Property Value As String
        Get
            Return _value
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _value = value
            _mre.Set()
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub WaitUntilSolved()
        _mre = New Threading.ManualResetEvent(False)
        _mre.WaitOne()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You're blocking the UI thread. You can't do that if you expect the UI to remain responsive. Why are you trying to use multiple threads?

Comment: @Enigmativity Hi, I was under the impression that Task.Run does the work in a background thread.  Trying to use multiple threads for exactly the reason you mentioned, to keep my parent form's UI responsive.  Perhaps I should use an event instead?

Comment: You're clearly blocking the UI thread though. Ah, I see. You're creating a new form inside the `Task.Run` - you can't do that. All of your UI must run on the UI thread. You can only run non-UI code on a different thread.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks that helped me fix it,  I only put answer.WaitUntilSolved + the Debug.WriteLine part in Task.Run and it's working exactly as I had intended.

Comment: The worker thread you use has no dispatcher loop.  So none of the normal UI plumbing can work.  No painting and no user input events, you'll see at best a frozen window without content.   Not only is this wrong, it is dangerously easy to solve.  You'll get into big trouble by code you cannot see.  Lots of controls in the toolbox internally use the events provided by the SystemEvents class.  When they fire, inevitably the control gets the event fired from the wrong thread.  This deadlocks your app in a completely undiagnosable way.  Don't do it.

Comment: @HansPassant Hi Hans, am I able to safely work with UI controls in BG threads using the Invoke method of said UI control?

Comment: Your snippet shows no evidence of needing any threading at all.  Use ShowDialog() instead of Show().

Comment: @HansPassant ShowDialog only returns execution when Form.Close is called from what I've tried.  That is not how I intend it to work in my specialized case, but admittedly there is extensions beyond the scope of my question which I intend to make.  P.S. I've solved the question thanks to Enigmativity, I realize it was a rookie mistake..

Comment: Instead of waiting on a specific line, why not just create a custom event in your `Answer` class and raise that in the setter of `Value`? For instance: `Public Event Solved As EventHandler`.

Comment: @VisualVincent Hi, thanks for the response.  I am indeed considering it, I was just trying to avoid using events tbh.

Comment: But why though? In cases such as this, using events is by far much better practice than blocking execution because there simply is no need to do the latter. It would've been different if you were building for example a console application, which terminates the program after the last line of code has been executed inside `Main()`. But since the UI thread in WinForms constanly runs a message loop you don't have that problem, and therefore can afford to respond to events only when they happen.

Comment: If you're doing this because you don't always want to execute the same code when the event occurs, you should know that there are workarounds. In Visual Basic 10.0 [**Lambda Expressions**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions) were introduced, which lets you write inline methods to simplify your coding process. Here's an example using events, as you see I'm subscribing to the `WebBrowser` control's `DocumentCompleted` event with two different (even nested) lambdas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42366199/3740093